# How to use a non-git repository as a dependency for a git project?

Tags: git, github, ncurses

I have a project on GitHub that uses ncurses. How would I add ncurses as a dependency, seeing as the ncurses source code doesn't have an official repository on GitHub? The source code is in the form of gzip tar of course.

Comment: I'd put a presence/version check in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* needed source dependencies to ncurses, you can find mirrors on GitHub.
For instance, https://github.com/mirror/ncurses.

The best practice would be to declare a binary dependency, or, as suggesting, simply checking if ncurses is installed:

- at least a script, like `ls -la /usr/include/ncurses.h`
- or a [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/develop7/fish-shell/commit/d9e6ef3b967240042202642392379d85933e44cc), which is then [used by `automake` to generate a `Makefile`](https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en).